# how to give a unique serial number to each scenario in a feature file using cucumber jvm and selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

Since there are too many scenarios , when there is failure or error I find it difficult to jump to the scenario which has the problem.

Is there a way to give a unique number to each scenario so that it is easy to map and can be used in logging too .

I am using selenium webdriver with cucumber jvm and pageobjects.

eg of feature file :

```
    #1
    @regression @CPM_PI @visibility
    Scenario Outline: To check if CPMPI panel is visible
    Given Go to Nerd
    And set Team="CTM"
    And set Client="PQR"
    And set Broker="ABC"
    And select Product="CPM"
    And set Revenue"1000000"
    And set Revenue(CY)="500000"
    And tick Coverages="CPM/PI"
    And select Main Activity="<MainActivity>"
    Then check CPMPI visible


    #2
    @regression @CPM_PI @visibility
    Scenario: To check visiblity of all CPMPI panels
    Given Go to Nerd
    And set Team="CTM"
    And tick Cyber 
    Then check panel Cyber visible
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take some time to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  It will help you write questions that get faster/better responses (and avoiding downvotes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply "tag" your scenario names like:

```
Scenario Outline: Scenario 1: To check if CPMPI panel is visible
Given Go to Nerd
And set Team="CTM"
And set Client="PQR"
And set Broker="ABC"
And select Product="CPM"
And set Revenue"1000000"
And set Revenue(CY)="500000"
And tick Coverages="CPM/PI"
And select Main Activity="<MainActivity>"
Then check CPMPI visible


#2
@regression @CPM_PI @visibility
Scenario: Scenario2: To check visiblity of all CPMPI panels
Given Go to Nerd
And set Team="CTM"
And tick Cyber 
Then check panel Cyber visible
```

Make it a habit to give your scenario tagged names

Comment: @Grant Winney , i tried doing it but it says 'Vote up requires 15 reputations '